# how to check if the NLog has finished logging the messages from its queue in asynchronous mode?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

i have a NLog config file as below. For some reasons, the NLog needs to in asynchronous processing.

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  autoReload="true">
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:/log1.log" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I would like to know if there any method i can use to check if the NLog finished logging messages, something as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
{
    LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("this is for testing " + i);
}
while(!LogManager.finished())  // check if finished or not
{
    Console.Write(".");
}
Console.Write("done");
```

Thanks.

Look

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a boolean you could check, but you could call `flush` - when that call is done, the logging is finished.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
{
    LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("this is for testing " + i);
}
LogManager.Flush(); //flushes all async targets and block until done. There is also an optional timeout.
Console.Write("done");
```

See [LogManager methods](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/Methods_T_NLog_LogManager.htm)

Comment: @llook was this where you were looking for?

Comment: LogManager.Flush() does not wait synchronously, so we cannot give guarantee that before closing application everything get logged properly.

Comment: Flush is synchronously. See [code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/cb1df12dc7c88508957356e7db2436f47d82ecd3/src/NLog/LogFactory.cs#L593). But there are no guarantees as there is a timeout. (Which could be set manually)

Comment: Flush seems synchronous but it just hit some internal code to say that let's finish the pending messages but it does not wait to finish all of them, so internally it seems asynchronous.

Comment: Yes because there is a timeout.